# How do you convert a number and store it in a char array and then convert the char array to String so that it prints the integer?

Tags: java, arrays, char, render-to-string

I have a char array with four characters stored, and I need to add an integer to the char array and then add .txt to the end of if, then render the whole thing as a string so I can use it to create a file object. But when I run the whole process it doesn't work. Using println to output what is going on at every step it shows me that the number stored in the char array is printing to string as this: ( 0001 ) instead of just this (1). Why is that and how do I work around it? I typed up a short version of the segment of code here to demonstrate the problem. The output of the printline statement below is this: temp 0001 .txt instead of temp1.txt which is what I'm trying to get. Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int count = 4;
  char[] temp = new char[count + 5];
  char[] base = new char[] {'t', 'e', 'm', 'p'};

  char[] extension = new char[] {'.', 't', 'x', 't'};
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     temp[i] = base[i];

  temp[count] = (char)1;
  for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
     temp[count + 1 + k] = extension[k];

  String file = new String(temp);

  System.out.println(file);

  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have to keep it as an array? I mean you could just do `s = new String(base) + Integer.toString(theNumberToAdd) + new String(extension);`

Comment: @FabianN. And the explicit call to `Integer.toString()` is even optional here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i am bit too carefull since I am doing much Javascript atm and don't want to run in a `number = '6' * 1` in Java

Comment: Yes, the actual program is more complex and I'm having to make multiple file names from a base file name, so I'm extracting everything before the extension (.txt) into a char array, then afterwards adding the number to the char array by using a cast int variable from a for loop.

Comment: It is very important to understand the difference between the `int` value `1` and the `char` value `'1'`. Or more generally, the difference between a numerical value and the characters which are displayed to represent that number.

Comment: Take a look at the simpler approach to solve your problem in my answer. And sing with me: *no char arrays when we can use String* :)

Comment: I don't like it when the OPs just walk away without accepting any answer. Are our efforts to go in vain? :(

Comment: I apologize, I didn't realize how this works. New to programming and this site. I accepted the answer that helped me solve the problem. Again, sorry for being ignorant of how it works, but thanks for pointing it out so I can do better!

Comment: Oh, and I clicked the check mark next to the answer, I'm assuming that's how you accept it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will insert the char with the value `1` instead of the character 1.

```
emp[count] = (char)1;
```

Try this instead:

```
emp[count] = '1';
```

Edit:
If you want it more dynamically

```
int i = ...
emp[count] = (char) ('0'+ i);
```

Comment: In the actual program I'm making I have to create multiple file names with different numbers (temp1.txt, temp2.txt... etc) through a loop, how can I make it work in that situation since I need to assign the number in the file name string based on casting an int variable from a for loop into a number?

Comment: so it will be temp[count] = (char)i; where i is the counter in a for loop.

Comment: This will fail if `i >= 10`. It is safer to use `Integer.toString()`.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JimboSakahana What is the largest value you need for `i`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice his original code would not work for i >= 10 either and he asked for char-arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to take all the hassles with character arrays. Java has done most of the job for you with [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Try this simpler code, to create 10 file names. I think you are trying to create a number of files with numbered names having same base name.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String baseName = "temp";
    String extension = ".txt";
    
    // create 10 file names
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      String newName = baseName + (i+1) + extension;
      System.out.println(newName);
    }
  }
}
```

Note the parenthesis around `i+1`. Without parenthesis, `i` and `1` are cast to string separately, and are then concated to the string. For example, if `i` is `5`, then without parenthesis this gives `51`, whereas with parenthesis you get `6`.

**Bonus**:
You can pad the number part with `0`s like this:

```
String newName = baseName + String.format("%04d", i+1) + extension;
```

With this, the numbered part is padded with zeros to make length 4 if the length is less than 4. However if the length if 4 or greater than 4, the number does not get stripped.

For example: `45` becomes `0045`, `12345` stays `12345`

Answer (score 1):

The value that you are trying to assign to `emp[count]` is the ascii value of 1

What you want is the ascii value of `1` which is 49, so you could do

```
emp[count] = 49;
```

or

```
emp[count] = 48 + 1;
```

or

```
emp[count] = '1';
```

**Edit** As per your comments, if all that you are trying to do is created a new file name then these `arrays` are not even needed.

See the answer from @Code-Apprentice

```
String file = base + 1 + extension;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the `+` operator works specially with strings to concatentate them. On top of that, anything is automatically converted into a `String` when the other operand of `+` is a `String`. So you can do all of this in a single line:

```
String file = base + 1 + extension;
```

Notice that 1 is not special here. It is a value with type `int`. So you can easily replace it with a variable name instead.